# How to maintain two Gitolite repositories?

Tags: gitolite

As a newbie to Gitolite would like to know how to handle or maintain two gitolite instance setup at 2 different servers which are at different location as an gitolite-admin.

Its like:

@ VM 'A' at location X we have one Gitolite instance and
@ VM 'B' at location Y we have another Gitolite instance.

but the repository is the same on both of the instance,say "projectrepo.git" but  different set of users will be committing actively @ both of the locations.Additional requirement is like both the repos should be in sync.

pls. advise.

Comment: so you want to keep to copies of the same repo, in sync on 2 separate instances, with 2 separate sets of users committing to them, in sync?  This would be huge nightmare, if they really are the same repo...

Comment: @Doon , yes I'm looking to keep a single or same repository in sync on 2 gitolite instances with users checking @ both of the instances.
Any input is really appreciated ! I know its going to be a nightmare ;)

Comment: I know is an old question, but gitolite has a feature called mirroring: https://gitolite.com/gitolite/mirroring.html